# For faculty positions that require three years of research experience excluding PhD, how is that time calculated?

Tags: job-search, postdocs, faculty-application

Usually an applicant for a faculty position in different Indian academic institutes requires to have at least three years of research experience excluding his/her PhD. The time span may differ depending on the institutes and/or particular country. I was wondering how does one calculate the time span of research experience?

More particularly, does that 'experience' start with just joining a postdoc position or defending  one's thesis or only after obtaining the formal degree?

Comment: I suspect what's actually required is not actually research _experience_ (or to more accurately describe what you seem to be asking about, _time after PhD_), but rather research _results_.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by research *results*? Usual advertisement for assistant professorship at IITs in India reads like : "At least 3 years teaching / research / industrial experience, excluding however, the experience gained while pursuing Ph.D. " 
For associate professorship this is 6 years teaching / research / industrial experience.

Comment: Is there that much of a difference between defending a thesis and formal degree?  I'm not familiar with the Indian system, but my interpretation would be 3 academic years, rather than 36 months, so I wouldn't think there would be too much difference in most cases, provided you get a postdoc right after your PhD.

Comment: Yes. Most of the time people join postdocs (specially in India institutes) just submitting their theses. They defend their theses usually 6-8 months later.

Comment: _Sorry, what do you mean by research results?_ --- Strong publications, with first authorship (if that matters in your field). My point is that the outcome of your research is likely to matter far more than the time you've spent doing it, no matter what the ad says.

Comment: OK, I understand. I think then the research experience in a necessary criterion to apply for that position. But research results will decide whether one will be given the job. :-)

Answer (score 2):

According to recent notification from UGC, research experience during PhD can also be included for teaching post.

Specially, in a [notice](http://www.ugc.ac.in/pdfnews/4478237_UGC-clarification-.pdf) dated 1 March 2016, it says:

> The issue regarding counting of the period of active service spent on pursuing Ph.D. was considered by the UGC in its 512th Meeting held on 4th February, 2016.
>
> The clarification of University Grants Commission is as follows:
>
> "the period of active service spent on pursuing Research Degree i.e. for
>   acquiring Ph.D. degree simultaneously without taking any kind of leave may be counted as teaching experience for the purpose of direct
>   recruitment/promotion to the post of Associate Professor and above."

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a supporting citation, such as a link to this notification you mention and the relevant quote from it?

Comment: @ff524 : I have modified my answer. See if it useful now.

Comment: Recently this notification came into limelight in media but there is still glitch in it.

Comment: 'Period of active service' does it mean full time PhD student? By the way, in some earlier job advertisement, they mentioned it clearly that 'experience during PhD study' would not be considered.